# Is there any way to communicate between my .exe application and Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, cookies, clipboard

Is there any way to communicate between my .exe application and Firefox?

Because, I have my own webpage. I'm using FireFox to browse it.

I have an application (in c++) to process a piece of HTML code from my webpage within FireFox. My application can print something directly to printer (raw print).

Since now, I coudn't access firefox's DOM content (page HTML source) from outside firefox; Also, I coudn't print directly to printer (raw print) from firefox.

Now, I'm looking solution for this problem. Here are my possibilities:

1.) My web page I can copy my related text to clipboard.

2.) My web page I can write my related text to Firefox's cookie.

3.) My web page I can write my related text to a file from client's PC.

4.) Any other way to send my related text to my .exe application.

But I don't know how can I do:
How can I copy to clipboard within firefox,
How can I read FireFox's cookie from my .exe application,
How can I create file in client's PC.

Is there any way to communicate between my .exe application (in c++) and Firefox?

Comment: What language is your .exe application written in?

Comment: You can use [nsIFile and related](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O) and write to a file that your app reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your page has a true URL outside of FireFox, you could solve your problem by registering a custom protocol handler. E.g. register "X-myprettyprinter". Then, in FireFox, from `http://www.example.com/index.html` you can redirect to `X-myprettyprinter:http%2D%2Dwww.example.com/index.html`. FireFox doesn't know how to handle the X-myprettyprinter protocol so it hands off the URL to the OS, which then hands it to your registered application. Bonus: it works for all browsers. Downside: you have to retrieve the URL yourself and render the page again in-process

Answer (score 3):

You have to write an extension for firefox an use its API. For example see [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIProcess):
"The nsIProcess interface represents an executable process."

Answer (score 0):

You could write an addon for firefox that allowed some form of integration with your application.

[Here is a tutorial on writing firefox addins.](http://mytechieself.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-to-writing-firefox-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to skip the .exe application and just make an ad on for FireFox, Take a look at the FireBug ad-on. It can pull certain codes out of a web page, If you use the API I bet you could do what your .exe program should.